# Prevent attaching to Notes & Attachments while adding to Quote PDFs

Tags: attachment, quote

I have a trigger that will save the Quote as PDF in Quote PDFs section (QuoteDocument object) whenever the status is updated to Accepted. The problem is, it also attaches to Notes & Attachments section. Is there a way to suppress attaching to Notes & Attachments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The system is designed to show it in both places.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/88213)

Comment: It does provide an answer. While @DavidSchach might elaborate more on the background of the two related lists, this is an answer (and, I believe, a correct one).

Comment: @VigneshwaranG Please tell me how else to answer a Yes/No question. It's not appropriate to ask for a workaround as it is about suppressing something, not finding a way to do something. So please support your assertion that it does not provide the answer the OP is looking for.